# Find the value of a function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to figure out the value of the function if myFunc(16). I've coded up some javascript that I thought would work but the bracket about return says it's looking for ;

I've closed lines that don't need to close to see if I forgot something. I've moved lines around to see if that made a difference. I've tried defining num to 16.

```
myFunc(16)

function myFunc(num){
    var m = num mod 2;
    var n = 1;
    var result = 0;

    for (n = 0; n < 5; n++) { 
        result = result + (m*n); 
    }
    return result;
}
```

I'm trying to find the value of the function if myFunc(16) honestly I haven't coded in a while I'm just getting back into it. It's probably something super simple and I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: Sorry, but I wasn't able to understand your question... Can you let it more clear?

Comment: Did you print the result?

Comment: by `mod`, you probably mean the modulo operator `%`, but note that this will cause m to be 0 for even numbered inputs, rendering a zero result

Comment: This question needs to be clearer about 1) What you expect to happen and 2) what is actually happening. As it is, you're just going to get people speculating in the answers in the hopes of getting a few reputation points. Please try to be clearer about what you are asking, so that you can get informed help. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this solution ,

```
myFunc(15)

function myFunc(num){
    var m = num % 2; //mod => '%'
    var n = 1;
    var result = 0;

    for (n = 0; n < 5; n++) { 
        result = result + (m*n); 
    }
    return result;
}
```

If your num will not divisible by 2 then it will give some output otherwise if your number is divisible by 2 , it will always gives you `0`

Comment: Happy to help you . Most Welcome . @Saenz

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the result of the function to a variable.

```
var myVariable = myFunc(16)
```

Then you can look at myVariable and check its value, print it, etc.

It looks like you have a syntax error in your code as well.  Has it thrown any errors?

Comment: It says SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier for mod

Comment: @Saenz the Modulus operator is defined as `%`

Answer (score 0):

- mod should be. %
- n = 0 should be. let n = 0

  ```
  function myFunc(num){
      var m = num % 2;
      var n = 1;
      var result = 0;

      for (let n = 0; n < 5; n++) { 
          result = result + (m*n); 
      }
      return result;
  }
  ```

Hope it helps! :) don't mind that, questions are always useful.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, the fundamental error is that "`mod`" is spelled "`%`" in Javascript.  But you also don't need to declare `n` outside the `for`-loop.  And you haven't shown how you're testing your result (for instance, via `console.log`.)  Fixing those things gets this:

```js
console .log (
  `16 => ${myFunc (16)}`,
)

console .log (
  `17 => ${myFunc (17)}`,  
)

function myFunc(num){
  var m = num % 2;
  var result = 0;

  for (var n = 0; n < 5; n++) { 
    result = result + (m * n);
  }

  return result;
}
```

But modern JS mostly forgoes `var` statements for `const` or `let` ones.  So this is probably an improvement:

```js
function myFunc(num){
  const m = num % 2;
  let result = 0;

  for (let n = 0; n < 5; n++) { 
    result = result + (m * n);
  }

  return result;
}
```

This is where you probably want to leave that function, but if you choose, you might improve it with more modern techniques.

Javascript does not have a built-in `range` function, but with a helper function, we might be able to clean up that code using [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
function range(lo, hi) { return [...Array(hi - lo)].map((_, ctr) => lo + ctr); }

function myFunc(num){
  return range(0, 5).reduce((total, ctr) => total + ctr * (num % 2))
}
```

Finally, [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) offer some readability advantages, and you could take advantage of them here:

```js
const range = 
  (lo, hi) => [...Array(hi - lo)].map((_, ctr) => lo + ctr);

const myFunc = (num) =>
  range(0, 5).reduce((total, ctr) => total + ctr * (num % 2))
```

While your mileage might vary, I find each of these steps a real improvement on its predecessor.